# Importing a namespace vs importing selected classes

Tags: vb.net, namespaces

I am working on a project where I have a class library with about 50 different classes in this library. In my application, is it better to import the specific classes that I need for that particular form or module or is it better to just import the entire namespace even if I only need a few of the classes? Over the course of the app I will use them all, but will only use a few for each form or module.

For example:

```
Imports ProjectClasses 'This namespace has approx 50 classes with in it

Public Class formMain
  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim objProject = New CProject
    Dim objElement = New CElement
  End Sub
```

Is it better to just import the particular class vs the entire namespace?

```
Imports ProjectClasses.CProject
Imports ProjectClasses.CElement

Public Class formMain
  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim objProject = New CProject
    Dim objElement = New CElement
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the answer should be neither.  Your library should probably be broken down by area/project/functionality, and then you should be importing whatever you need for a particular project.

If that's nt feasible, then import the whole namespace -- if this causes problem you have probably picked some bad class names.

Comment: Is there a performance hit for importing the whole namespace vs just importing selected classes?

Comment: @NativeNevadan: No, it all happens at compile time, no performance hit possible.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would probably be to create overrides of each of the classes you will be using. And use those without namespace prefix (since they will be in your current scope anyways). If you plan to use many, you can divide them into functional groups.

With this approach, if you decide to introduce new functionality, you only need to do it once. Also, if your controls vendor decide to change how it works, you may be able to add compatibility layer, so that your old code does not break when upgrading to the new version. All done in one place of your code.

Of course, it depends on how long you will be on this project, how complicated it is/will be, if your vendor is yourself etc.

Comment: Not sure I understand the overrides part.  I was trying to figure out if it's better to import the entire namespace (which contains many classes) or just the individual classes for that particular form.  This class library is only for this project.  I'm the author of both the application and the library.  Is there a performance hit for importing too many classes, even if they aren't used in that form or modual?

Comment: @NativeNevadan: If it's all yours, and just this project - you can disregard my recommendation. There isn't any performance hit with referencing whole namespaces. You only need to care about name collisions, and clutter in your `Intellisense`.